# How to check if a string column in pyspark dataframe is all numeric

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, numeric

I have a PySpark `Dataframe` with a column of `strings`. How can I check which rows in it are Numeric. I could not find any function in PySpark's [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).

```
values = [('25q36',),('75647',),('13864',),('8758K',),('07645',)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['ID',])
df.show()
+-----+
|   ID|
+-----+
|25q36|
|75647|
|13864|
|8758K|
|07645|
+-----+
```

In Python, there is a function `.isDigit()` which returns `True` or `False` if the `string` contains just numbers or not.

Expected DataFrame:

```
+-----+-------+
|   ID| Value |
+-----+-------+
|25q36| False |
|75647| True  |
|13864| True  |
|8758K| False |
|07645| True  |
+-----+-------+
```

I would like to avoid creating a `UDF`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A simple cast would do the job :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

my_df.select(
  "ID",
  F.col("ID").cast("int").isNotNull().alias("Value ")
).show()

+-----+------+
|   ID|Value |
+-----+------+
|25q36| false|
|75647|  true|
|13864|  true|
|8758K| false|
|07645|  true|
+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. This definitely works. I thought that might be some inbuilt function as well. If I don't find a one, I will click this one as an answer.

Comment: **Pay Attention!** It's better to use `long` rather than `int` because of the integer range of -2,147,483,647 to +2,147,483,647.

Answer (score 5):

I agree to @steven answer but there is a slight modification since I want the whole table to be filtered out. PFB

```
df2.filter(F.col("id").cast("int").isNotNull()).show()
```

Also there is no need to create a new column called ***Values***

---

Alternative solution similar to above is -

```
display(df2.filter(f"CAST({'id'} as INT) IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: OP wants a new column, not a filter

Answer (score 5):

### Filtering with Regex

Indeed I enjoyed the creative solution provided by Steven but here is my much easier suggestion for this kind of situation:

```
df.filter(~df.ID.rlike('\D+')).show()
```

Firstly, you select every row which contains a non-digits character with `rlike('\D+')` and then excluding those rows with `~` at the beginning of the filter.

Comment: OP wants a new column, not a filter

Answer (score 2):

The clearest way to search for non-numeric rows would be something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select("col_a",F.regexp_replace(col("col_a"), "[^0-9]", "").alias("numeric"))\
    .filter(col("col_a")!=col("numeric"))\
    .distinct()\
    .show()
```

Comment: OP wants a new column, not a filter

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can also build a custom `udf` for this purpose:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def is_digit(val):
    if val:
        return val.isdigit()
    else:
        return False

is_digit_udf = udf(is_digit, BooleanType())

df = df.withColumn('Value', F.when(is_digit_udf(F.col('ID')), F.lit(True)).otherwise(F.lit(False)))
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for no UDF.

Answer (score 1):

```
df=spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("source_table.csv")
df=df.withColumn("is_valid",lit("true"))
df.withColumn("is_valid",when(col("age").cast("int").isNotNull(),col("is_valid")).otherwise("false")).show()  # this will work 
#if you want to use rlike this will work
pattern="^[0-9]*$"
source_df=df.withColumn("is_valid",
               when(col("age").rlike(pattern), col("is_valid")).otherwise("false"))
```

Comment: Very nice, because you avoided the use of an udf function..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is Scala language

```
spark.udf.register("IsNumeric", (inpColumn: Int) => BigInt(inpColumn).isInstanceOf[BigInt])
spark.sql(s""" select "ABCD", IsNumeric(1234) as IsNumeric_1  """).show(false)
```